# GROUP BY with HAVING clause does not return a row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Strange problem with a GROUP BY and HAVING clause on SQL Server 2014.

It's distinctly possible I've done something wrong, but I cannot make sense of this.

**Here's the setup data:**

```
create table #accounts(accountid int)
create table #data(accountid int, categoryid int, asofdate date, datavalue numeric(20, 10))

insert into #accounts
    values 
    (1),(2),(3)

insert into #data
    values 
    (1, 10, '1/31/2015', 0),
    (1, 10, '2/28/2015', 10),
    (1, 10, '3/31/2015', 20),
    (2, 10, '1/31/2015', 0),
    (2, 10, '2/28/2015', 15),
    (2, 10, '3/31/2015', 25),
    (3, 10, '1/31/2015', 0),
    (3, 10, '2/28/2015', 7),
    (3, 10, '3/31/2015', 12)
```

**This returns a single row... for 1/31/2015. The only date with a total of zero**

```
select categoryid, asofdate, sum(datavalue) as totalvalue
from #accounts a
inner join #data d
    on d.accountid = a.accountid
group by d.categoryid, d.asofdate
having sum(datavalue) = 0
```

Result is `10, '1/31/2015', 0`

**Yet, somehow the following does not return any rows... I'm basically asking it to give me the Max date from the first query. Why does this balk?**

```
select categoryid, max(asofdate) as MaxAsOfDate, sum(datavalue) as totalvalue
from #accounts a
inner join #data d
    on d.accountid = a.accountid
group by d.categoryid
having sum(datavalue) = 0

drop table #accounts
drop table #data
```

Yet it returns no rows... baffled.

**SQL Fiddle here:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e44cb/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, because you are Grouping by `d.categoryid` - And there is no grouping by this column, which would return `0` for `sum(datavalue)`:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e44cb/4 (it's 89)

If you could add your *expected output* to your post, we might be able to help you with the query you need.

Answer (score 3):

By removing the GROUP BY asOfDate, you've removed any groups that have SUM()=0.

You should make your first query a derived table or CTE, and then do the MAX outside of it to get your desired results.

Comment: Gave dognose the win since he showed me what was wrong first... will probably go with the CTE approach.